# Boyer Moore - Bad character rule implementation substring search

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, substring

I am trying to implement bad character rule from boyer moore with 2D array for sub string search and I am running into scenario where in I see my arr[0][1] is getting overlapped with arr[1][0] which is causing issue. I tried to walk over code in VS and if I look at memory location then it actually shows correct value, but I am not sure while printing how this overlap is happening. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong ?

**Erroneous output**
Value of  j is   ---     0

New entry is  --- f  102       13

Inside while loop --  102      13

Inside while loop --  13      -1   **// overlapping of 13 happening y ?**

```
 # define ROWS 20
  # define COLUMNS 1

 int main(void)
    {
        string str = "firstcharacter";
        int strlength = str.length();
        int arr[ROWS][COLUMNS];
        memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr[0][0]) * ROWS * COLUMNS);

        for (int i = 0; i < strlength; i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            bool flag = false;
            // check till point previous character was inserted
            while (arr[j][1] != -1)
            {
                // if previous character is already present 
                // just update value dont insert character
                if (arr[j][0] == str[i])
                {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }

            if (flag == true)
            {
                int value = strlength - i - 1;
                arr[j][1] = value;
                cout << " Old entry is  --- " << str[i] << "  " << arr[j][0] << "     " << arr[j][1] << endl << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                int value = strlength - i - 1;
                arr[j][0] = str[i];
                arr[j][1] = value;
                cout << " New entry is  --- " << str[i] << "  "<< arr[j][0] << "     " << arr[j][1] << endl << endl;
            }   

            for (int x = 0; x < strlength; x++)
            {
                cout << " Inside while loop --  " << arr[x][0] << "     " << arr[x][1] << endl;      // --- error case after first iteration only I see value overlapping
            }
        }

        cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < strlength; i++)
        {
            cout << " final table is " << arr[i][0] << "     " << arr[i][1] << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What are `ROWS` and `COLUMNS`?

Comment: sorry forgot to copy that part of code - updated the question with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `COLUMNS` is `1`.  `ary[j][1]` and `ary[j+1][0]` will point at the same memory address, although the first is technically undefined behavior because the `[1]` subscript is out of range,

Comment: Wouldnt COLUMNS = 1 create two columns  0 and 1 ?

Comment: @ifelse COLUMNS=1 creates one column, with index 0.  If you want 2 columns (indexed with [0] and [1]) you need to set COLUMNS to 2.